# Subir archivos a carpeta especifica

Tags: php, file, upload

Quiero subir un archivo a una carpeta especifica, pero la ruta la estoy sacando de una consulta de base de datos, pero cuando le doy subir me lo guarda en la ruta raíz.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registros WHERE id_prod = '$id'") or die("consulta".mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$dir = $result['dir_archivo'];

$archivo = (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : null;
if ($archivo) {
   $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $extension = strtolower($extension);

   $extension_correcta = ($extension == 'PDF' or $extension == 'pdf' or $extension == 'AI' or $extension == 'ai');

   if ($extension_correcta) {

      // $ruta = $dir.$archivo['name'];
      // $ruta_destino_archivo = $ruta;
      // $ruta_destino_archivo = "archivos/{$archivo['name']}";
      $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $dir.$archivo['name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a lo que yo utilizo te puedo facilitar el siguiente script

```
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name']; //Obteniendo el nombre del archivo
$ruta_destino = "miruta/cualquiera/";

//$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = la carpeta raiz donde esta el proyecto
$carpeta_destino=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $ruta_destino;

//Movemos el archivo al directorio temp al directorio deseado.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto_perfil']['tmp_name'], $carpeta_destino . $nombre_archivo);
```

El codigo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` puede ser reemplazado por algun lugar que elijas en el disco duro del servidor; por ejemplo una carpeta destinada a fotos de perfil de usuaris.

Comment: El error se me presenta es cuando saco la ruta por consulta sql, es decir, consulto la ruta y sale "carpeta/imagenes" y cuando trato de subir otra imagen por esa ruta no me deja,  como que no la reconoce..

Comment: @EduardoRamirez si me muestras como tienes la ruta almacenada en la base de datos puedo ayudarte